# What is the scientific name of such a fungus?

Tags: mycology

Several days ago, in a bush I found the fungus as attached which is about 25cm in height and does not look like an edible mushroom:

[image]

Any one has an idea of its scientific name and other details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks pretty much like a Coprinus comatus (also known as: shaggy ink cap, lawyer's wig, or shaggy mane) to me. You can see the characteristic ring around the stipe of the fungus (see image below from [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schopf-Tintling)). The fungus is edible and is also cultivated in China for this purpose. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprinus_comatus) for more details.

[image]